# PackageProvider, GetHostedIntelliTypes Errors Logged in VS2012 ActivityLog.xml

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've freshly installed Vs2012 Professional and have the following error in the ActivityLog.xml.It's seems that error started happening after an install of Tfs Express 2012 with Update 2

The errors logged seem to involve PackageProvider it that makes any sense.

Any help that anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Andrew

```
<entry>
    <record>432</record>
    <time>2013/06/06 18:01:11.816</time>
    <type>Warning</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Unexpected system error mode before loading package [ProviderPackage]</description>
    <guid>{5F2E5E42-4192-4D79-A0D8-1D881E808829}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>433</record>
    <time>2013/06/06 18:01:11.816</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [ProviderPackage]</description>
    <guid>{5F2E5E42-4192-4D79-A0D8-1D881E808829}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>434</record>
    <time>2013/06/06 18:01:11.847</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [ProviderPackage]</description>
    <guid>{5F2E5E42-4192-4D79-A0D8-1D881E808829}</guid>
    <hr>80131522</hr>
    <errorinfo>Method 'GetHostedIntellisenseTypes' in type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Progression.DTEWrapperCached' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.GraphProviderPackage, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' does not have an implementation.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>435</record>
    <time>2013/06/06 18:01:11.847</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [ProviderPackage]</description>
    <guid>{5F2E5E42-4192-4D79-A0D8-1D881E808829}</guid>
    <hr>80131522</hr>
    <errorinfo>Method 'GetHostedIntellisenseTypes' in type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Progression.DTEWrapperCached' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.GraphProviderPackage, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' does not have an implementation.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

To fix the problem, go to control panel -> filter the installed program by "SQL" -> find **Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Data-Tier App Framework**. -> right click and select **Repair** option. Wait the program to be repaired. 
Start your VS 2012 again. You error should go away.

Good Luck!

http://www.sdlcengineering.com/